# Can I stop the for loop from continuing on the last index of the array I am iterating over?

Tags: python, iteration, continue

I made a code for the "piling up challenge" on Hackerrank and it is supposed to iterate through a list and check whether the elements of the list are in descending order.

```
    for i in range(1, len(l)):
            if l[i - 1] < l[i]:
                print('No')
                break
        
           else:
                print('Yes')
                continue
```

However, with the else statement, if the list is correctly sorted in descending order, it will repeatedly print 'yes' for every iteration in the loop. Is it possible to just print a single 'yes' on the very last iteration of the loop if all elements meet the condition? Thanks!!!

Comment: Set a flag, remove the else clause, and defer printing the solution outside the loop

Comment: You don't need the `continue` in the `else` case, that's going to happen anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use of the less well-known `for: else:` construct:

```
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if l[i - 1] < l[i]:
        print('No')
        break
else:
    print('Yes')
```

The `else:` paired with the `for:` only executes if the loop completes successfully. [See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) for some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that all the elements are sorted. Then try to find one example abolish this thesis.

You can use a variable defining sorted order, then assign correct value through loop. This way there will be no need to log 'yes' every time.

```
sorted_order = True
for i in range(1, len(l)):
  if l[i - 1] < l[i]:
    print('index '+ (i-1) +' and '+ i +' are in incorrect order')
    sorted_order = False
    break

if sorted_order:
   print('true')
else
   print('false')
```

Comment: You don't seem to know much about python. The Boolean values in Python are `True` and `False`, and `sorted` has the same name as a built-in function.

Comment: True, I have not been using Python for 5 years now:) Thank you for your explanation @Mechanic Pig

Answer (score 0):

You can use `else` after `for` loop, if the loop is not jumped out by the `break` statement, it will execute after the loop:

```
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if l[i - 1] < l[i]:
        print('No')
        break
else:
    print('Yes')
```

But some people may not like this way. I prefer to use `any`:

```
if any(l[i - 1] < l[i] for i in range(1, len(l))):
    print('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

It's more Pythonic to cooperate with `pairwise` (in Python3.10):

```
from itertools import pairwise

if any(i < j for i, j in pairwise(l)):
    print('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

Faster way:

```
from operator import lt
from itertools import starmap, pairwise

if any(starmap(lt, pairwise(l))):
    print('No')
else:
    print('Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. By having a function you can use multiple data. This code is also faster by at least 50%.

```
def is_sorted_better(x):
    # If a single item is larger than the last item, then you return 'no'
    if any(x[i - 1] < x[i] for i in range(1, len(x))):
        # You can add any extra lines for if it isn't in order here
        return 'no'
    # if all items have been checked and there are no issues, return yes
    # You can place additional code here like 'sorted_order = True'
    return 'yes'
```

Code with no comments here:

```
def is_sorted_better(x):
    if any(x[i - 1] < x[i] for i in range(1, len(x))):
        return 'no'
    return 'yes'
```